# JavaScript validate username while user is typing

Tags: javascript, html

I made a register page and the registering itself works cause I made php check on submit if username and other things are correctly written, but I went a step further and wanted to validate the passwords while the user is writing, and if two passwords dont match to mark them with red, and if they match to mark them with green. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for whatever reason - can anybody help me?

```html
<div class="form-content">
    <form name="regform" method="post" action="register.php<?php if ($referral_code !== '0') {echo '?r='.$referral_code.'';}?>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username"><?php echo $t_username_reg; ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="" id="username" name="username" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email"><?php echo $t_email_reg; ?></label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password_1"><?php echo $t_password_reg; ?></label>
            <input type="password" id="myInput" name="password_1" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password_2"><?php echo $t_confpassword_reg; ?></label>
            <input type="password" id="myInput1" name="password_2" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-remember">
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()"><?php echo $t_showpass_reg; ?>
            </label><a class="form-recovery" href="login.php"><?php echo $t_alreadymem_reg; ?></a>
        </div>
        <p><?php echo $t_byreg1_reg; ?><a href="tos.php"><?php echo $t_byreg2_reg; ?></a><?php echo $t_byreg3_reg; ?><a href="pp.php"><?php echo $t_byreg4_reg; ?></a>.</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" name="reg_user"><?php echo $t_title_reg; ?></button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#myInput").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#myInput1").val();
    var element = document.getElementById("username");

    if (password != confirmPassword)
        element.classList.add("red");
        element.classList.remove("green");
    else
        element.classList.add("green");
        element.classList.remove("red");
}
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#myInput, #myInput1").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});
```

Comment: [`if...else...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else): _"To execute multiple statements within a clause, use a block statement (`{ ... }`) to group those statements. **In general, it is a good practice to always use block statements**"_

Comment: How is this issue related to PHP? As far as I can tell, it' just about js?

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of problems, first when using if+else statement, you need to use the brackets `if{} else{}`, that was throwing an error. Also you need to define `.red` and `.green` in `css`. This is enought to make the password matching things work:

```js
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    
    var password = $("#myInput").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#myInput1").val();
    var element = document.getElementById("myInput1");
console.log(password, confirmPassword);
    if (password != confirmPassword){
        element.classList.add("red");
        element.classList.remove("green");
    }
    else{
        element.classList.add("green");
        element.classList.remove("red");
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#myInput, #myInput1").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});
```

```css
.red{
  color:red;
}
.green{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-content">
      <form name="regform" method="post" action="register.php<?php if ($referral_code !== '0') {echo '?r='.$referral_code.'';}?>">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username"><?php echo $t_username_reg; ?></label>
          <input type="text" class="" id="username" name="username" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email"><?php echo $t_email_reg; ?></label>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password_1"><?php echo $t_password_reg; ?></label>
          <input type="password" id="myInput" name="password_1" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password_2"><?php echo $t_confpassword_reg; ?></label>
          <input type="password" id="myInput1" name="password_2" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-remember">
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()"><?php echo $t_showpass_reg; ?>
          </label><a class="form-recovery" href="login.php"><?php echo $t_alreadymem_reg; ?></a>
        </div>
        <p><?php echo $t_byreg1_reg; ?><a href="tos.php"><?php echo $t_byreg2_reg; ?></a><?php echo $t_byreg3_reg; ?><a href="pp.php"><?php echo $t_byreg4_reg; ?></a>.</p>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" name="reg_user"><?php echo $t_title_reg; ?></button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have entered both passwords as different. Still not showing the output.

Comment: when the passwords are different, it is the username input text color that changes... it was like that in the OP. I agree it is not really practical, but anyway i think @Just Another Coder can take it from there...

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder No ? When you run the snippet, enter something in the first input (user name) and than enter something in the last 2 inputs (passwords)

Comment: I edited my code so it is the 2nd password input that turns red or green when it is different from the first password.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check below code:

```js
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#myInput").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#myInput1").val();
    var element = document.getElementById("username");

    if (password != confirmPassword)
    {
        element.classList.add("red");
        element.classList.remove("green");
    }
    else
    {
        element.classList.add("green");
        element.classList.remove("red");
        }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#myInput, #myInput1").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});
```

```css
.red {
color :red;
}

.green {
color :green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-content">
    <form name="regform" method="post" action="register.php<?php if ($referral_code !== '0') {echo '?r='.$referral_code.'';}?>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">USername</label>
            <input type="text" class="" id="username" name="username" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password_1">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="myInput" name="password_1" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password_2">Confirm password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="myInput1" name="password_2" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" name="reg_user">Register</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```